# String not showing on Tableview from ComboBox in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, java

I've been trying to display what I choose from combo box to table view in Java. I've spent hours already searching for a solution but no avail. I am not having any errors but I can't seem to display a string on TableView. I would like to ask for assistance.

MainView.java has the combo box and the button to click where it should add the string from combo box to table. I've skipped some code.

**MainView.java**

```
public class MainView extends Application {
  public static String selectedItemComboBox;

  Button btnAdd = new Button(Constants.BUTTON_ADD);

  btnAdd.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {  
      selectedItemComboBox = comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString();
      ReportManager.showCart();
      ReportManager.addToTable();
    }
  });
}
```

Here's the ReportManager class. I store the string from combo box to an ArrayList later to pass it to ObservableList as I saw on one example on web.

**ReportManager.java**

```
public class ReportManager {

  public static void addToTable(){
        if(ReportCart.details.isEmpty()){
        ReportCart.details.add(new JasperTableModel(MainView.selectedItemComboBox.toString()));
        System.out.println(jasperList.toString());
    }else{
        if(ReportCart.details.contains(MainView.selectedItemComboBox)){
            System.out.println("Selected Jasper File already added to cart.");
        }else{
            ReportCart.details.add(new JasperTableModel(MainView.selectedItemComboBox.toString()));
            System.out.println(jasperList.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my other View class which has the TableView.

**ReportCart.Java**

```
public class ReportCart extends Stage{
  public static TableView<JasperTableModel> tableView = new TableView<>();
  public static ObservableList<JasperTableModel> details = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new JasperTableModel("TEST"), 
        new JasperTableModel("TEST1"),
        new JasperTableModel("TEST2"));

    public static void start() {
      ObservableList<String> details = FXCollections.observableArrayList(ReportManager.jasperList);
      tableView.getColumns().add(jasperFileNameColumn);
      jasperFileNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(data -> new SimpleStringProperty(data.getValue()));
      tableView.setItems(details);
  }
}
```

**JasperTableModel.java**

```
public class JasperTableModel {

    public final SimpleStringProperty fileN;

    public JasperTableModel(String fileNn) {
        this.fileN = new SimpleStringProperty(fileNn);
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileN.get();
    }
    public void setFileName(String fNamee) {
        fileN.set(fNamee);
    }
}
```

I can get the value to my ArrayList, but I can't display it on my TableView. The ObservableList is empty. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you display a hard-coded String in your table view?

Comment: @Emanuel i've tried to display a hard-coded String to my table view, but it only displays blank space. I can click, but no display. any ideas? thanks!

Comment: I'll try to reproduce your problem today.  Did you initialize your table view in the initialize() methode? (setCellValueFactory...)?

Comment: I do not have initialize() method unfortunately. I've updated my codes above. tried to follow the documents on Oracle website. I am trying to show the "TEST", "TEST1", and "TEST2" strings but it only shows blank spaces on my table view.